# Android Accessibility Service - GestureDescription.Builder - Complex Gesture Swipe not dispatched correctly

Tags: android, touch, swipe, gesture, accessibilityservice

the problem is Gesture is not correctly dispatched. Not all points are swiped.

I tried to make a rectangle swipe. If the duration is long it is dispatched not perfect but almost perfect.

Here's what I'm using from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service/#0

```
private void configureSwipeButton() {

        Button swipeButton = (Button) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
                    Path swipePath = new Path();
                        swipePath.moveTo(500, 500);
                        swipePath.lineTo(900, 500);
                        swipePath.lineTo(900, 900);
                        swipePath.lineTo(500, 900);
                        swipePath.lineTo(500, 500);

                    gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(swipePath, 0, 1500));

                    dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), null, null);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried doing this on sketch app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonymobile.sketch&hl=en

Here's the result of Duration of 1500:
https://prntscr.com/odq1cn

Here's the result of Duration of 1000:
https://prntscr.com/odq2qj

Here's the result of Duration of 500:
https://prntscr.com/odq2xs

Here's the result of Duration of 100:
https://prntscr.com/odq3li